# Page does not load using window.href after login but loads when i go to url before login

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-router, window.location, location-href

I am trying to redirect the user after login is done so I used `window.location` inside my Login.js that redirects to `Home.js`. However, after succesful login the page redirect to the url but doesn't load the page. But if I manually try to access the page before login then the page loads succesfully.

index.js:

```
import ReactDOM from 'react-dom';
import './index.css';
import Login from './Login'
import Home from './Home'
import {Route, BrowserRouter, Switch} from 'react-router-dom'
import {GlobalProvider} from './globalContext'

function Router(){

  return (
    <React.StrictMode>
        <BrowserRouter>
          <GlobalProvider>
            <BrowserRouter>
              <Route exact path ='/success' component={Home}/>
              <Route exact path ='/' component={Login}/>
            </BrowserRouter>
          </GlobalProvider>
        </BrowserRouter>
    </React.StrictMode>
  )
}

ReactDOM.render(
  <Router/>,
  document.getElementById('root')
);
```

Login.js:

```
import React, {useState, useContext, useEffect, setTimeout} from 'react';
import {login, returnCredentials} from './auth';
import  { GlobalContext } from './globalContext';

var hasLoginned = false;

export default function Auth(){

  const [username, setUsername] = useState('');
  const [password, setPassword] = useState('');

  const {tokenValue} = useContext(GlobalContext);
  const [token, setToken] = tokenValue

  useEffect(()=>{
    if(hasLoginned){
      console.log("token=",token);

      if(token){
        window.location = 'https://localhost:3000/succes'
      }
    };
  }, [token])

  const loginClicked = () => {
    login(username, password) // stores JSON object with access and refresh tokens.
    var credentials = returnCredentials()
    hasLoginned = true
    window.setTimeout(function(){
      console.log("credentials: ",credentials, "it has type of ", typeof(credentials))
      console.log(credentials[0])
      setToken(credentials[0])
    },2000)
  }

  return (
    <div>
      <label htmlFor="username">Username</label>
      <input id="username" type="text" placeholder="username" value={username}
        onChange={evt => setUsername(evt.target.value)}/>
        <br/>
      <label htmlFor="password">Password</label>
      <input id="password" type="password" placeholder="password" value={password}
        onChange={evt => setPassword(evt.target.value)}/>
        <br/>
      <button onClick={loginClicked}>Login</button>
    </div>
  )

}
```

Home.js:

```
export default function Home(){
    return (<div>Hello there!</div>)
}
```

What should I do?

Comment: Rather than using `window.location` I will suggest you to use `react-router-dom` which is easier to use and has resourceful documentation which you can find it [here](https://reactrouter.com/web/guides/quick-start). Thank you.

Comment: You can use the ```useHistory``` from ```react-router-dom``` to push the user to success page

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Use This**

```
window.location.href =  'https://localhost:3000/succes'
```

**OR**

```
import  { Redirect } from 'react-router-dom'
```

```
<Redirect to='/succes'  />
```

Answer (score 0):

Instead of using window.location ,
Use `useHistory` from react-router-dom.

```
import { useHistory } from "react-router-dom";

let history = useHistory();

history.push("/success")
```

Link you can refer : https://reactrouter.com/web/api/Hooks

Comment: useHistory is gonna change the history stack of `BrowserRouter` be careful !!